# Error in rock mongo configuration

Tags: php, php-5.5, rockmongo

I am using rockmongo in php application, it throws error message like

"Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\rockmongo\rock.php on line 457"

```
function rock_name_to_java($name) {
    $name = preg_replace("/_([a-zA-Z])/e", "strtoupper('\\1')", $name);
    return $name;
 }
```

Please help me !!!

Comment: Are you using any framework. I have seen similiar problem with before on drupal framework

Comment: I am trying to run rock mongo app on xamp server.

Comment: Then do what message is saying above, use this `preg_replace_callback `

Comment: I dont know as I am very new to rock mongo

Comment: Please just try with code what i gave above. It is not rock mongo problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function rock_name_to_java($name) {
   return preg_replace("/\/_([a-zA-Z])\/e/", "strtoupper(\\1)", $name);
 }
```

How about this

Comment: Now it throws "preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'strtoupper('\1')', to be a valid callback in C:\xampp\htdocs\rockmongo\rock.php on line 458"

Comment: It is working when i tested it. Please give me your input $name

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because preg_replace() has been deprecated and will likely be removed from future versions.

Instead, do this. *Note, I didn't test it.

```
$name = preg_replace_callback(
   "/_([a-zA-Z])/e",
   function ($matches) {
     return strtoupper($matches[0]);
},
 $name
);
```